# is there a library to create repeated events every week in java?

Tags: java, task

i am creating a web application in Java and I need advice on which is the best library to create events that repeat on certain days of the week. For example every Tuesday at 9:00 am. I need it to create a software to manage the heating of the house.

P.S: if there is a better language than java to do this, suggest it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're looking for a Cron scheduler, take a look at [cron4j](https://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/), quartz or spring scheduler